# strange Chrome 16 float bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

today I noticed one of the sites I created has a strange behavior:
the content is split up into two floating divs, #section on the left and #aside on the right. they're floated according to their position, ie. #section -> left; #aside -> right.

I had no problem with this when I created it (1.5 years ago) and don't have now... except Chrome (16.0.912.x). the site is http://irierocktrio.com/

when I load it in Chrome, the #aside first appears in its place and when the page completes loading it slips on the left, over #section. if I start Chrome's dev console (ie. "Inspect element"), look for #aside's css, uncheck and re-check the float attribute, the div gets into it's place. if I reload the page, slips off again. it's even stranger that it does this only on the front page (Home), however the other pages (except blog) are on the very same structure.

I thought, what if I try to set #aside to float left to, and give it a few px left margin just to keep off from #section: the very same happens, it slips over #section, if I re-check the float attribute in dev console, it goes to it's place.

I just can't understand this. anybody can figure this out?

UPDATE: I've submitted a bug report to Google. Today (10.02.2012) I noticed Chrome 17.0.xxx, but this issue still presists.

Comment: This is also in Chrome 18 Dev. Channel and Chrome Canary

Comment: You should probably file a bug against Chrome: http://new.crbug.com

Comment: so you say it's not my fault, or bad coding, but a browser bug? I'll report it then, just wanted to make sure it's not me. Thanks!